# Inverse of a normal distribution with absolute values

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I want to calculate the minimum $n$ that I need so that
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{|M_n-\mu|<0.1\right\}=0.9$$
where $M_n$ is an estimator of the median. I have already calculated (in a previous section of the exercise) that
$$\sqrt{n}(M_n - \mu)\equiv N\left(0, 1.5 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)$$
Therefore:
$$\mathbb{P}\left\{|M_n-\mu|<0.1\right\}=\mathbb{P}\left\{|Z| < \frac{0.1\sqrt{n}}{1.5 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}=0.05319\sqrt{n}\right\} = 0.9$$
However, I don't know how to proceed from here. Can someone help me?
**Observation**: I know the solution is $n \geq 95639$, but I want to know how to get there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $\mathbb P(|Z| \lt z) =0.9$ then $z=\Phi^{-1}(0.95) \approx 1.644854$

If $0.05319\sqrt{n} > 1.644854$ then $n > \left(\frac{1.644854}{0.05319}\right)^2 \approx 956.3$

which suggests there may be an issue of powers of $10$ somewhere